# How do I write QList Stored items using qt's QTextStream?

Tags: c++, qt, qlist, qtextstream

That is how i tried it at first but i get an error "no operator found that takes a left hand operand of type 'QTextStream' or there is no acceptable conversion"

```
    QList<QString>lNamesList;

    void write(){

        QFile data("E:/Test/output.h");

        if (data.open(QFile::WriteOnly))
     {
            QTextStream out (&data);

         nameList.append("Name1");

            out << NameList;

        }
    }
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    write();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: `QTextStream` doesn't work on a `QList`, but you can write your own simple loop for that, or what is the problem? Replace `out << NameList;` with `for (const QString & name : nameList) out << name;`

Comment: Thank you and you are Right. it worked with a loop like you said but changed it into foreach instead of for

Answer (score 1):

You cannot feed your `nameList` directly to your `QTextStream`. You can give it a `string or QString`. So you might want to loop over your `QList` which would look something like this:

```
for(const QString& str : nameList){
    out << str;
}
```

note: see [the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextstream.html) for more info

Comment: You are right. i couldn't feed my List into Qtextstream. But i kept getting an error with the for loop also . so i fixed it with a foreach loop like this.                                                                                                                                foreach (const QString& str , NameList){
            out << str;
        }

Comment: The C++ for each loop is "new" since C++11, what you're using is the Qt specific old style macro. You can still use it, but standard C++ is usually preferred if you use the new syntax features. if you want to use the new C++ versions you can to that in your Qt project settings file, I think it's still not enabled by default. `CONFIG += c++11` if your compiler supports it.